# How can I sum multiple Numeric textbox value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendonumerictextbox

I have multiple Numeric textbox as shown below in the snippet, all are currency format textbox's.  How can I sum the values of textboxes in Class Name `Charges` and display the total `sub-total-Of-Charges` textbox and subtract if any value in textbox's with `class=sub` from `sub-total-Of-Charges` textbox value.

I have used the following jQuery Code which is working but two problems.

1. Doesn't Keep the currency format
2. the value of `net-invoiced-amount` is updated only when I update textbox value in textbox class .sub same thing `.sub-total-Of-Charges` value is updated on `.Charges` are updated but I need to re-calculate or update the value `net-invoiced-amount` or `.sub-total-Of-Charges` whenever .sub or .charges textbox's values are changed.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("change", ".charges", function () {
        var calculated_total_sum = 0;

        $(".charges").each(function () {
            var get_textbox_value = $(this).val();
            if ($.isNumeric(get_textbox_value)) {
                calculated_total_sum += parseFloat(get_textbox_value);
            }
        });
        $(".sub-total-Of-Charges").val(calculated_total_sum);
    });
   ```

   $(document).on("change", ".sub", function () {

   ```
        var netInvoicedAmount = $(".sub-total-Of-Charges").val();

        $(".sub").each(function () {
            var get_textbox_value = $(this).val();
            if ($.isNumeric(get_textbox_value)) {
                netInvoicedAmount -= parseFloat(get_textbox_value);
            }
        });
        $(".net-invoiced-amount").val(netInvoicedAmount).trigger("change");
    });
   ```

   });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get  reference of textbox where you need to set the updated value using `data("kendoNumericTextBox")` and then set new value using `.value("newwvalue")` this will update new value according to the format which you have set earlier .

Also , use `$(this).attr("aria-valuenow")` to get the original value of textbox without any currency and change your selector to `$(".k-formatted-value.charges")` to get only input value from particular textbox .Currently , when you will inspect html generated it has 2 input box with same class that's the reason total sum is not working.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$("#TotalDirectLaborCharges, #TotalIndirectLaborCharges, #TotalContractCharges, #TotalTravelCharges, #TotalAdjustments, #TotalAdjustments, #CostsAlreadyPaid, #Other, #NetInvoicedAmount ,#SubtotalOfCharges").kendoNumericTextBox({
  decimals: 2,
  format: "c"
});

//add both selector
$(document).on("change", ".charges,.sub", function() {

  var calculated_total_sum = 0;
  $(".k-formatted-value.charges").each(function() {
    //get original value without currecny
    var get_textbox_value = $(this).attr("aria-valuenow");
    if ($.isNumeric(get_textbox_value)) {
      calculated_total_sum += parseFloat(get_textbox_value);
    }
  });
  //get kendo textbox
  var numerictextbox = $("#SubtotalOfCharges").data("kendoNumericTextBox");
  //set value
  numerictextbox.value(calculated_total_sum);


});
//add both selector
$(document).on("change", ".sub ,.charges", function() {
  //get value from inputbox
  var netInvoicedAmount = $("#SubtotalOfCharges").data("kendoNumericTextBox").value();
  $(".k-formatted-value.sub").each(function() {
    //get original value
    var get_textbox_value = $(this).attr("aria-valuenow");
    if ($.isNumeric(get_textbox_value)) {
      netInvoicedAmount -= parseFloat(get_textbox_value);
    }
  });
  //set value in invoice amt
  var numerictextbox = $("#NetInvoicedAmount").data("kendoNumericTextBox");
  numerictextbox.value(netInvoicedAmount);

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.1021/styles/kendo.common.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.1021/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.1021/styles/kendo.default.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.1021/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.1021/js/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.1021/js/jszip.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.1021/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div class="quarter m-l-lg m-y text-right">

  <label class="m-r-lg required" asp-for="TotalDirectLaborCharges">Total Direct Labor Charge<br /></label>
  <input id="TotalDirectLaborCharges" class="charges" /><br />
  <label class="m-r-lg required" asp-for="TotalIndirectLaborCharges">TotalIndirectLaborCharges<br /></label><br />

  <input id="TotalIndirectLaborCharges" class="charges" /><br />
  <label class="m-r-lg required" asp-for="TotalContractCharges">TotalContractCharges</label><br />

  <input id="TotalContractCharges" class="charges" /><br />

  <label class="m-r-lg required" asp-for="TotalTravelCharges">TotalTravelCharges</label><br />

  <input id="TotalTravelCharges" class="charges" /><br />
  <label class="m-r-lg required" asp-for="TotalAdjustments">TotalAdjustments</label><br />

  <input id="TotalAdjustments" class="sub" /><br />

  <label class="m-r-lg required" asp-for="CostsAlreadyPaid">CostsAlreadyPaid</label><br />

  <input id="CostsAlreadyPaid" class="sub" /><br />
  <label class="m-r-lg required" asp-for="Other">Other</label><br />

  <input id="Other" class="sub" /><br />
  <label class="m-r-lg required" asp-for="SubtotalOfCharges">SubtotalOfCharges</label><br />

  <input id="SubtotalOfCharges" readonly class="sub-total-Of-Charges" />

  <br />

  <label class="m-r-lg required" asp-for="Other">NetInvoicedAmount</label><br />

  <input id="NetInvoicedAmount" readonly class="netInvoicedAmount" />

</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Swati Thank you! only one thing Net Invoiced Amount doesn't change when i update Charges, NetInvoice Amount changes only when .sub are changed :)

Comment: Ahh :P i didn't saw that ..wait i will update that as well

Comment: Hi , check updated code i have just added both selector `sub` and `charges` to both events .Also , you can merge them together .

Answer (score 1):

As you've used jQuery for your project, I'm also writing this answer using the library.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let $references = {
    subtotal: $('#SubtotalOfCharges').first(),
    net: $('#NetInvoicedAmount').first(),
    fields: {
      subtract: $('input.sub'),
      charge: $('input.charges')
    }
  }
  
  function calculateSum($elements) {
    return Array.from($elements).reduce((previousValue, element) => {
      val = $(element).val();
      
      if(val)
        previousValue += parseFloat($(element).val());
      
      return previousValue;
    }, 0)
  }
  
  $(document).on('change', 'input', function() {
    let sum = {
      subtract: calculateSum($references.fields.subtract),
      charge: calculateSum($references.fields.charge),
    }
    
    $references.subtotal.val(sum.charge);
    $references.net.val(sum.charge - sum.subtract);
  });
})
```

```css
input,
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Total Direct Labor Charge</label>
<input id="TotalDirectLaborCharges" class="charges">

<label>TotalIndirectLaborCharges</label>
<input id="TotalIndirectLaborCharges" class="charges">

<label>TotalContractCharges</label>
<input id="TotalContractCharges" class="charges">

<label>TotalTravelCharges</label>
<input id="TotalTravelCharges" class="charges">

<label>TotalAdjustments</label>
<input id="TotalAdjustments" class="sub">

<label>CostsAlreadyPaid</label>
<input id="CostsAlreadyPaid" class="sub">

<label>Other</label>
<input id="Other" class="sub">

<label>SubtotalOfCharges</label>
<input id="SubtotalOfCharges" readonly class="sub-total-Of-Charges">

<label>NetInvoicedAmount</label>
<input id="NetInvoicedAmount" readonly class="net-invoiced-amount">
```

**How does it work?**

1. Instead of manually triggering a `change` event whenever a `.sub` (or `.charges`) is changed, to calculate the subtotal/net amount, you can bind the event handler to both of the input groups and run the calculations once.
2. I've used `$references` to tidy up the code a little bit and a `reduce function` is used to calculate the sum of a field group.
3. `Array.from` is used to create a native Javascript array from the jQuery object.

For more information on `Array.reduce`, visit its documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), and for more information on `Array.from` visit [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

Finally, a feasible solution is to use input prefixes. Every UI framework normally has one built-in, otherwise, you can take a look at Bootstrap's input groups [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/) (Especially, `.input-group-prepend`).

Comment: Hi @Farsad Thank you, on your demo it works exactly how I wanted but I cant get it to work on my end, may be it because I use kendo numeric textbox?.

Comment: It might be due to that as well as other factors like whether your browser supports `Array.from` and `Array.reduce` or you might need a polyfill to use them. Anyhow, are there any errors in your console?

Comment: no error at all in the console thats the first thing I checked

Comment: May you add `console.log` after `let sum = {....}` (logging sum, and $references)?

Comment: Hi, nice answer :)